# Can rabbits and guinea pigs eat sparrow grass?

Tags: rabbits, feeding, guinea-pigs

I have a rabbit and a guinea pig kept together in my room. (They come along very well.)

I also happen to have a bunch of sparrow grass in front of me that I don't have any plans to do with. Could there be any trouble if I just feed it to the little guys?

Comment: https://squeaksandnibbles.com/can-rabbits-eat-asparagus/

Comment: @trondhansen aah, so it's also called asparagus! the more you know, thanks.

Comment: TL;DR: they can eat it.

Comment: i know very little about rabbits so other people needs to give you an answer to this,but it does look like you can give some sparrow grass to your rabbit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus

Comment: When I raised guinea pigs , I put them in a small fenced area of lawn ( N. ILL) and it looked like they ate everything green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparrow grass is the folk name for asparagus, as mentioned in the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus).

A German source [Kaninchenwiese.de](https://www.kaninchenwiese.de/ernaehrung/futterlisten/gemueseliste/) says:

> Spargel kann regelmäßig angeboten werden, wenn er gefressen wird. Akzeptanz: schlecht.

Which, translated to English, means:

> Asparagus could be frequently given to your rabbits. But in most cases, it's not well accepted and they do not like it very much.

The links lead to vegetable lists for rabbits ("Kaninchenwiese") and guinea pigs ("Meerschweinchenwiese"). Most vegetables are shown with pictures and all are marked with traffic light system:

- red means "do not feed";
- yellow means "not optimal" or "not well accepted";
- green means "you can feed it without being worried".

Asparagus (*Spargel* in German) in this system has been assigned a "yellow" according to these criteria.

In every case you should give your rabbit and guinea pig a variety of food to choose from. It is necessary to ensure that they would not eat some inappropriate food in case they are hungry.

Answer (score -1):

I found these websites helpful:
veggies for rabbits:
https://rabbitwelfare.co.uk/rabbit-care-advice/rabbit-diet/recommended-vegetables-herbs/

https://rabbit.org/suggested-vegetables-and-fruits-for-a-rabbit-diet/

veggies for guinea pigs:
https://www.guineapiggles.co.uk/guinea-pig-food-chart

you can find the calcium level on this site. High calcium level is bad for guinea pigs.

Comment: Most of the information in your answer is hidden behind the links and link-only answers are discouraged because they are not self-sufficient, could you please paraphrase this information and include it in the answer or just quote the most relevant parts with attributing the source, thanks.

Comment: What @lila means is it would be good if you could paraphrase the information regarding sparrow grass from the provided links, so your answer is self-contained (and also safe from link rot). Thanks for the links, they look useful!

Comment: I didn't find asparagus in the 'veggies for rabbits' list, but it is safe for guinea pigs, and it should be fed occasionally.